# Connect two Android devices using the socket through the Router

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

Android especially.

I will try to establish a connection between two devices (android - android) where one will create a server socket, connect the other device to the client, close the socket, and the connection between the two devices remains. So simple.

Server

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //// !!! only for test !!!
    (new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int port = 33000;
                SocketAddress allInterfaces = new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", port);
                ServerSocketChannel channel = MuxServerSocketChannelFactory
                        .openAndBindServerSocketChannel(null, allInterfaces, 3);
                ServerSocket server = channel.socket();

                Socket socket = server.accept();
                Log.i("test", "host was connected!!!: " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
                callback.onConnected(socket);
                server.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    })).start();

    if (true) return;
    //// !!! end test on real device !!!
}
```

Client

```
int privateServerPort = 33000;
int publicServerPort = 25000;
InetAddress privateServerIpAddr = InetAddress.getByName("172.23.9.120");
InetAddress publicServerIpAddr = InetAddress.getByName("xx.xx.xx.xx"); // correct IP address

Socket socket = new Socket(publicServerIpAddr, publicServerPort,
    privateServerIpAddr, privateServerPort);
// never connected
```

The problem arises when these devices are not in one LAN or in one, but via a VPN. It is not possible to create this connection at this time.
I've been looking for a long time here (Stackoverflow), but it does not work for me. Some of the Libraries I tried:

[Portmapper](https://github.com/offbynull/portmapper)

```
// Discover port forwarding devices and take the first one found
List<PortMapper> mappers = PortMapperFactory.discover(networkBus, processBus);
PortMapper mapper = mappers.get(0);
// mappers always return null
```

[Cling](https://github.com/4thline/cling)

```
final PortMapping desMapp = new PortMapping(
        33000,
        Tool.getLocalHost(false).getHostAddress(),
        PortMapping.Protocol.TCP
);
UpnpService service = new UpnpServiceImpl(new AndroidUpnpServiceConfiguration());
RegistryListener registryListener = new PortMappingListener(desMapp) {
    @Override
    public synchronized void deviceAdded(Registry registry, Device device) {
        super.deviceAdded(registry, device);
        // this callback is never call
    }
};
service.getRegistry().addListener(registryListener);
Collection<Device> all = service.getControlPoint().getRegistry().getDevices();
// the value all has 0 size
service.getControlPoint().search();
Thread.sleep(5000); // anything value
all = service.getControlPoint().getRegistry().getDevices();
// again the size is 0
```

Is there a really simple example of How the server and client should look?
All IP addresses and ports i know. I'm testing it on Huawei P9 Lite, Elephone P9000.
I do not work with UPnP, NAT and so on.
Thank you very much for your help.